# Rails 3 observers and current_user

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, observer-pattern

There is few similar questions on Stackoverflow about getting of current_user form Rails 3 observers, but basic ideas the same:

1) passing of current_user via

```
attr_accessor :current_user
```

in the model we need to observe.

But this unacceptable for me, as, i need to observer 10 models (create, update, delete actions), and i don't want to pass this on each action, for each controller.

2) Storing current user in Thread. Completely unacceptable.

So what is the best practice? And, let's say, i want to get not only current_user in my observer, but also, IP address?

Any ideas?

Comment: This is more or less frowned upon, and so for this reason its actually a bit tricky to pull off, and most likely will not feel very elegant in the end.

one reason (among multiple) is say for instance you need to import data into your rails program.  this has to now access your models and respective observers, however there is no current user if your working from a command line.  so now you've limited the app to only working behind a web server, and so something like a mass data import would become painful fast.

paste your code if you want, and then it might be easier to help

Comment: @spotman, thanks for your comment. Basically, my code will not be very useful here, because it's too general. 10 models like 'Item' (as example) with user_id, manageable by other users. This way user with id 1, can edit Itme.first.user_id (#=> 2). And i need observer to observe stuff, like (User1 updated Item1 created by User2). And, yes, limiting by web server is completely ok for me.

Comment: So what do you want to do with this data?  If your trying to do something like send an email to the person who did the updating, its often easier to maintain if you put this in the controller, especially if you are trying to avoid using attr_accessor to set something like updater_id, which you could then read in an observer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After investigating for more, i found it's totally useless to use Rails native observers in a such a tasks. Because, if you need to pass something from controllers, in my case it was current_user, this totally ruins observer's beauty.

So my answer to my own question is: still stuck with something like [acts_as_audited](https://github.com/collectiveidea/acts_as_audited)

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion would be to add a `last_modification_by` field to your model. In your observer you could then use that to figure out who made the change and who gets the notification.

Then have your view/controller code put the current user in that field.

This seems to me to be the safest approach. I'd worry about the observer using the current user - it feels to me that the current user should be divorced from the quasi background-processing that the observer is doing. (Which is why stashing the current user in a Thread - which I've used in the past with great success - feels wrong here also).

This approach (having a last_modified_by also lets you make modifications to records in batch - perhaps sending email to the owner of the record that, "The system has updated your record because (some daily processing routine happened). `last_modified_by` some created user which represents the system (or admin user).